# Is it possible to specialize for variadic std::function?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have question about having a `std::function` object as a data member for my class. I would like for it to accept two types of functions, either with one or two parameters of the same kind. Is there some strategy for doing this, perhaps involving template meta programming?

Here's a copy of my code so far, and to be clear I would like it to only accept `std::function<matrix (matrix, matrix)>`  and `std::function<matrix (matrix)>` .

```
 struct RegisteredOPS {

                using matrix = std::shared_ptr<Matrix::Representation>; 

                enum Type { NOP, MM, PLUS, ReLU,};
                Type        m_type;
                std::function<matrix (matrix, matrix)> m_func;
                RegisteredOPS(Type _typ, std::function<matrix
                    (matrix, matrix)> _fun): m_type(_typ), m_func(_fun) {}
                
            };
```

As a followup, I went and followed the suggestion of
@Lala5th, my question is if there is any way to wrap a functor object in `std::function<matrix (matrix, matrix)>` ?

I have the following Base class Functor adhering to CRTP:

```
        template <class Implementation>
        class BaseOp {

            public:
                virtual std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation> operator()(
                    std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>& l, 
                    std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>& r) {
                    return Impl().operator()(l, r); 
                }
                virtual ~BaseOp() = default;
            private:
                BaseOp& Impl() { return *static_cast<Implementation*>(this); }
                BaseOp() = default;
                friend Implementation;

        };
```

where I am attempting to pass it via this function:

```
 void RegisterOperator::visit(std::unique_ptr<MatrixMultiplyStep> mm) {

                std::string context_object_data = "Matrix_multiply";
                
                auto operand = mm->giveOperand();

                RegisteredOperation op = RegisteredOperation(
                    RegisteredOperation::MM,
&Matrix::Operations::
Multiplication::ParallelDNC::operator(),
                    std::make_pair(std::move(this->prev_operand), std::move(operand)));

                this->computational_graph.emplace_back(op);
                // mm->forward(std::make_unique<this>());

            }
```

However I ended up with this error.

```
tensor.cpp:20:42: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'NeuralNetwork::Computation::Graph::RegisteredOperation'
                RegisteredOperation op = RegisteredOperation(
                                         ^
include/tensor.h:59:21: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation> (Matrix::Operations::Multiplication::ParallelDNC::*)(std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation> &, std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation> &)' to 'NeuralNetwork::Computation::Graph::RegisteredOperation::Function' (aka 'variant<function<unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation> (unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>, unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>)>, function<unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation> (unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>)>, function<void ()>>') for 3rd argument
                    RegisteredOperation(Type _typ, std::string _dat, Function _fun, Operands _op):
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you are not constrained to c++14 then you could use `std::variant` from c++17. Otherwise you could implement some sort of union mimicking `std::variant`. You could also use some wrapper which wraps either `std::function<matrix(matrix)> -> std::function<matrix(matrix,matrix)>` (the second parameter being unused) and mapping `std::function<matrix(matrix,matrix)>` to itself, but depending on the use case that might be contrived. `f<m(m,m)> map(f<m(m)> x){ return [](m a, m){return x(a);};}` and `f<m(m,m)> map(f<m(m,m)> x){return x;}`

Comment: What's an example use of this thing which might be a function taking one matrix or a function taking two matrices?

Comment: Yes and example use would be registering a function to the `RegisteredOPS` object. It is either a functor that takes in a single matrix or two matrices as an argument. I went ahead and made a `using Function  = std::variant<std::function<matrix (matrix, matrix)>, std::function<matrix (matrix)>>;
`
shown here with the object as a data member

`Function m_func;`. I'm still new to std::variant and learning it so I will leave the question open if there are any other approaches! Thanks everyone

Comment: Your example doesn't make much sense, no one call a function by either one parameter or two. not to say the function may not exist at all. (it make a little more sense if you require both 2 though)

Comment: btw, at `BaseOp& Impl() { return *static_cast<Implementation*>(this); }`. you cast it to derived only to return it as base.

Comment: It seems you need 2 classes/functions to handle unary or binary function.

Comment: The use isn't "I'm going to store this in a data member". Who is invoking that data member (or wherever it is copied to)? Are they calling it with a mix of arguments? (known only at runtime?)

Comment: Aside: `std::shared_ptr<Matrix::Representation>` or `std::unique_ptr<Matrix::Representation>`? They are not interchangeable

Comment: The idea behind what I'm doing is to store nodes in a computational graph, where every node has a pointer to its operands and another pointer to its unary/binary operator . So far I haven't thought of how each function is invoked at runtime, but I wanted to explore the `std::visit` method for `std::variant`. Sorry if this seems poor planned, I'm still learning a lot of the new language features as part of this project